# d3 line chart string as x axis domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have two javasrcript array for passing as data in d3.js line chart. I want to map string value as x axis domain. But its not mapping correctly. `Data2` array contains year as string values.

```
xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain(data2.map(function (d) { return d.year; })),
```

and then `lineGen(data2)` is giving NaN values.

JsFiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nyngd3sz/

Very new to d3.js. It might be a small mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: if the values look like numbers, then `lineGen(data2.map(Number))` should help. or in your other code, `return +d.year; }` to coerce a number like many d3 examples...

Comment: values are not numbers that is the problem. Data is string. like "Region 1","Region 2" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the values are strings and not numbers, you will have to use ordinal scales. Refer more [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales).

Try this way.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain(data2.map(function (d) { return d.year; }))
```

Comment: Used rangepoints instead of range and it worked out perfectly. Thank you very much.